# Running GUI app from terminal

Tags: android-studio

Recently I had a login loop issue in ubuntu. Based on some information, running gui apps from terminal can cause login loop problem in your machine. Is there any solution to prevent that issue not to happen again. Because I use android studio in ubuntu in my laptop. In order to start the app I should run this script ./studo.sh from the terminal

Comment: AFAIK it's only running GUI apps *with `sudo`* that sometimes causes login problems

Comment: I recently completed a project to mount android phone on terminal and all regular user files I ran `stat` on were owned by `root` with GUID `0`. I wonder if Android studio is somehow treating linx files like an android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A login loop can happen by the incorrect use of `sudo` in the `terminal` to start a GUI application.

Bad example...

`sudo gedit /path/filename`

Good example...

`sudo -H gedit /path/filename`

The difference is in the -H...

```
 -H, --set-home
             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
             variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
             password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
             be the default behavior.
```

Not using the -H can set these two files to root ownership, causing the problem...

`ls -al .*thority`

```
-rw------- 1 root root 439K Oct 12 09:44 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 root root   58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

Comment: yeah I did run multiple times gui application with sudo. Now I understand why this happened and how to prevent it. Thanks!

Comment: +1. There is a question here like "tell me everything that can go wrong using Sudo with GUI" If this answer isn't posted there already you should post it.